# Android 6: deleting a path from external storage causes download to hold up

Tags: android

I would like to know why deleting a directory from the external storage causes the next download to that directory to hold up for minutes. This only happens in Android 6.

I am using `DownloadManager` to download a file to a temporary directory in an external storage. Then, I copy the file to an internal storage for my app. Everything works fine.

To clean things up for the user, I want to delete the temporary directory from the external storage. But this causes the next download to hold up. The next download gets stuck at `STATUS_PENDING` status with the reason `PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY` for a couple of minutes. This only happens in Android 6.

This is the method I am using to delete the temporary directory:

```
   private boolean deleteRecursive(File path) {
        if (path.isDirectory()) {
            for (File file : path.listFiles()) {
                if (!deleteRecursive(file)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return path.delete();
    }
```

I am renaming the directory before I delete in order to get around an issue where the filesystem sometimes locks the directory (it says device is busy):

```
final File renamedTmpDir = new File(tmpDir.getAbsolutePath() + System.currentTimeMillis());
tmpDir.renameTo(renamedTmpDir);
deleteRecursive(renamedTmpDir);
```

So far, I've tried the following to resolve this issue:

- prepare the temporary directory before enqueuing the download, if the directory does not exist.

What went wrong, and what can I do to delete the directory without affecting the next download?

Comment: Do you actually need to delete the directory? You don't make that clear in your question. And deleting a directory to which a file should be written seems like something that would definitely cause problems. From the way you phrase your question I am actually kind of surprised that it works at all. Anyway can't you just delete the files in the directory instead of deleting the whole directory? That seems like the most obvious fix.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I don't have to delete the directory. Just thought it'd be good to do so because I am using users' external storage. Resorted to not deleting the directory for the time being.